# What should I do if limits of integration are ones where Dirac Delta gets Infinite?

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am working on an integral involving Dirac delta function. I am from Physics background. I know that if I integrate from a to b and in between there is a point where argument of Dirac delta function is zero then the answer to this integral is unity. What if at say 'a' the argument of Dirac Delta Function is zero. What should I do in that case? What if I have a Riemann Integrable Function along with Dirac delta function? Please help.

Comment: Would you show an example?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Composition_with_a_function and by definition $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(f(x))g(x)dx = \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{n}2 1_{|f(x)|<1/n}g(x)dx$

Comment: @Botond $\int_{0}^\infty\delta(sin(x))e^-{x}dx

Comment: You are no longer doing a Riemann integral, and it depends whether the set you are integrating over contains the endpoint $a$ or not. A Riemann integral is insensitive to finitely many points, but this integral is not.